# Como copiar ALGUNS arquivos da branch para a outra?

Tags: git, arquivo, branch

Tenho 2 branch, a "b1" e a "b2". Preciso copiar arquivos da "b2" que ta mais evoluída e passar para "b1", mas alguns arquivos não quero. Como faço?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estando na branch b1:

```
git checkout b1
```

Você pode usar o seguinte comando para pegar a versão mais nova do arquivo da branch b2:

```
git checkout b2 arquivo_mais_evoluido_1.txt
```

Se forem vários arquivos, você pode usar o mesmo comando acima para pegar todos os arquivos dentro de um diretório. Exemplo:

```
git checkout b2 diretorio/arquivos/mais/novos/
```